# IIS URL Rewrite: formaction custom tag-attribute ignored

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have a simple outbound URL rewrite rule on my IIS ASP.Net core 2.2 webserver (IIS version 8.5.9600.16384):

```
<outboundRules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="CustomTags" preCondition="" stopProcessing="true">
        <match filterByTags="CustomTags" customTags="Misc" pattern="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="Hello world!" />
    </rule>
    <customTags>
        <tags name="Misc">
            <tag name="button" attribute="formaction" />
            <tag name="input" attribute="formaction" />
            <tag name="input" attribute="type" />
            <tag name="div" attribute="class" />
        </tags>
    </customTags>
</outboundRules>
```

Using the rule on the `html` code:

```
<div class="card"></div>
<input type="submit" value="My button" formaction="/path-to-some-page" />
<button class="btn" type="button" formaction="/path-to-some-page">My button</button>
```

I get the following rewrites:

```
<div class="Hello world!"></div>
<input type="Hello world!" value="My button" formaction="/path-to-some-page" />
<button class="btn" type="button" formaction="/path-to-some-page">My button</button>
```

All my custom tags except the ones based on the attribute `formaction` is rewritten as expected.

**Question:** Why is the `formaction` attribute ignored/protected?

Comment: try to use the precondition tag:`<preConditions>      
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>` you could run failed request tracing to get more detail [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, I have tried using the precondition tag you suggest and it doesn't change a thing - and why do you expect it to solve my problem?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, how can I get a failed request trace to tell my why a custom tag wasn't rewritten? All I get is an entry with X *EvaluationsPerformed* and X *EvaluationsSucceeded*.

Comment: when you run failed request trcaing it will show that your rule is successful or not [image1](https://i.imgur.com/eySiw3w.png). this the faild requesting tracing web.config code `<tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="100-900" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>`.

Comment: I tried your rule at my side with asp.net core web application and its working weel it changed the custom tag also [image](https://i.imgur.com/iCOyDDt.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution to this issue, you can find here https://forums.iis.net/t/1245687.aspx.